# Strip white spaces on input

Tags: jquery

I have a field that does not need any white spaces. I need to remove any as they are entered. Here's what I'm trying... no luck so far

```
$('#noSpacesField').click(function() {
    $(this).val().replace(/ /g,'');
});
```

Comment: If you're trying to remove them as they're entered, you need to bind to `change`, `keyup`, `keypress`, etc. Binding to `click` isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use jQuery trim to remove leading and trailing white space

```
$.trim(" test case "); // 'test case'
```

To remove all whitespace...

```
" test   ing  ".replace(/\s+/g, ''); // 'testing'
```

To remove whitespace as it is entered...

```
$(function(){
  $('#noSpacesField').bind('input', function(){
    $(this).val(function(_, v){
      return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });
  });
});
```

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2csf7/68/)

Answer (score 17):

```
$('#noSpacesField').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ +?/g, ''));
});
```

This will remove spaces as you type, and will also remove the tab char.

Comment: I like simplicity, but I think I need to keep bind as in @Kyle's example. Thanks

Comment: This accomplishes the same thing as my answer.

Comment: @Kyle it does now. However when I posted this you had your answer set as just a trim. After I posted this, you edited your answer to add a keyup.

Comment: @Bot I apologize. Keep on keepin' on.

Comment: Great..worked with ie11, edge, chrome, mozilla with jquery 3.3

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanna put numbers, try this! :D

```
$("#id").keyUp(function(){
   if(isNaN($(this).val())) {
     $(this).val(0);
   }
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ +?/g, ''));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the desired outcome with pure javascript.

Input

```
<input type="text" id="whiteSP" onChange={ (e)=>removeSpace(e) } />
```

Js Function

```
function removeSpace(e){
    let val = (e.target.value).trim();
    console.log(val);
}
```

However on a form submit button clicked

```
console.log( ( (" test case ").trim() ).replace(" ", "") )
```