# How to trim spaces dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use [input component](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) from material library. User inputs to fileld `several spaces + several symbols + several spaces`. After that he click on submit button. In result, console displays only symbols (without begin/end spaces). Its OK, its right behavior.

But i need begin/end spaces disappeared after user press key up. Help me do it.

[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-material-input1)

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Title</label>
  <input ng-model="$ctrl.pass">
</md-input-container>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.change()">submit</button>

class HomeCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.pass = null;
    this.change = function() {
      setTimeout(_ => {
        console.log(this.pass, 'length:', this.pass.length)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ng-trim='false' to input element (default will be true) so that AngularJS will not automatically trim the input.
`<input ng-model="$ctrl.pass" ng-trim="false">`

Update this.pass in the change() function as follows:

```
this.pass = this.pass.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //to remove all whitespaces
this.pass = this.pass.trim(); //to remove leading and trailing whitespaces

this.change = function() {
      this.pass = this.pass.replace(/\s+/g, '');
      setTimeout(_ => {
        console.log(this.pass, 'length:', this.pass.length)
      });
}
```

References:

- [Strip white spaces on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010275/strip-white-spaces-on-input)
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D